# is the probability of a function increasing on a larger interval smaller than the probability of a function increasing on a smaller interval?

Tags: calculus, probability

is the probability of a function increasing on a larger interval smaller than the probability of a function increasing on a smaller interval?

the function is differentiable and is increasing over a certain interval.

Comment: Where does the probability come in? What are you selecting randomly? *How* are you selecting it randomly?

Comment: If $A \subset B$, then "$f$ increasing on $B$" implies "$f$ increasing on $A$", so $P(\text{$f$ increasing on $B$}) \le P(\text{$f$ increasing on $A$})$.